# JavaScript: Html ID is not responding to Object literal in js

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason when I refer to the id "hi"(I know could've had a better name) in js it doesn't seem to recognize it. I think it has to do with the object itself.

```js
var ChristmasHotel = {
  var name: 'ChristmasHotel',
    var rooms: 50,
      getHotelName: function() {
        return this.name;
      }
};


var moreName = document.getElementById('hi');
moreName.textContent = ChristmasHotel.name;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to <span id='hi'>Null</span></h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: I think this is the first time I've ever seen a code snippet inside a code block. How is this possible?

Comment: I don't even know how this happened

Comment: You ruined the epicness @ibrahimmahrir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors with your code:

1. The closing `</html>` tag was missing a closing `>`.
2. In objects you don't put `var` before when declaring keys.

```js
var ChristmasHotel = {
  name : 'ChristmasHotel',
  rooms : 50,
  getHotelName : function(){
    return this.name;
  }
};


var moreName = document.getElementById('hi');
moreName.textContent = ChristmasHotel.name;

//You can also use:
moreName.textContent = ChristmasHotel.getHotelName();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to <span id = 'hi'>Null</span></h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice catch although I think the `</html>` won't be of any significance.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It prevented this code snippet from working.